# Google Sheets Query, Sort is out of order

Tags: google-sheets

when using the Query function to sort the numbers are out of order. otherwise, the formula is working fine.

It will basically sort as follows;
1
11
12
13
15
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
21
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Is there a way to get it to sort correctly in numerical order?

Thank you!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example

Answer (score 1):

your input is not numerical. you need to convert it and then it will sorts correctly. now (as you shown in your example) it sorts in alphabetical order

to convert it you can for example multiply your column by 1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that the format of your data is numerical and not in plain text. You can set the format by highlighting the range of data and apply numerical formatting by using Format > Number > Automatic.

On the other hand, you can use a combination of ARRAYFORMULA within a query formula:
`=query({A1:A21,ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A21*1)}, "select Col1 order by Col2")`

[image]

Comment: As for formatting, I have tried it with, Automatic, Plain Text, and Number. All of the formatting options are sorted the same. 

Here is the Formula I'm using for context. the Multiple sheets are about 30 different sheets. maybe I'm using it the wrong way. 
=Arrayformula(Query({Multiple Spreadsheets},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10 Where Col1 is not null Order by Col19"))